# Do I have to use .then when using async/await in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await

Just as the title says do I need to use .then when inside a async/await function. What's the efficient way between the two

```
setPersonList = async ()=> {
  const personList = [];
  await this.firestoreCollection
  .get()
  .then(result => {
    personList  = { ...result.data };
  });
  return personList ;
};
```

or

```
setPersonList = async () => {
  const personList = [];
  const snapshot = await this.firestoreCollection
  .get()
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      personList .push(doc.data());
  });

  return personList ;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not a good idea to combine async/await with then/catch chains on the same promise.  The whole point of async/await is to allow for more readable code that doesn't involve nesting callbacks with then/catch.

Your second option is much more idiomatic JavaScript.

Comment: if the second option is better where should I put my catching of error?

Comment: @Merndev you just need to wrap your call with a `try/catch` unless I'm not understanding your question properly